# javascript $_GetJSON from .php file

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a PHP file (GenerateJson.php) that uses json_encode to produce JSON data from my database, I know I can have that same PHP file write to a .json file but if I do that the written JSON will only contain the data from the last time the GenerateJson.php the requested and I want to javascript to be able to access live data on the fly

currently my code is is this:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');
    $.getJSON('Generated.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul class="searchresult1">';
        $.each(data.data, function(key, val) {
            if ((val.artists.Artist.search(myExp) != -1)) {

                var ArtistURL = "music/abArtist.php?artist=" + encodeURIComponent(val.artists.Artist);
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<a href="'+ ArtistURL +'"><h2>' + val.artists.Artist + '</h2></a>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#update1').html(output);
    });
});
```

When I replace "Generated.json" with "GenerateJson.php"

This javascript don't work anymore...

What is a good and simple fix? to get this to work with "GenerateJson.php" and how?

Thanks!

Comment: Use ajax to get the json from your server

Comment: then you have to point at your php script and generate the data on the fly. the alternative is to add caching logic to the php code. `if (json is more than X seconds old) { generate new json file }; spit out json file`

Comment: Is there any error in console? @MarcB

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the JSON data dynamically from PHP you can try the following

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'GenerateJson.php',
  done(function( data ) {
     var output = '<ul class="searchresult1">';
        $.each(data.data, function(key, val) {
            if ((val.artists.Artist.search(myExp) != -1)) {

                var ArtistURL = "music/abArtist.php?artist=" + encodeURIComponent(val.artists.Artist);
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<a href="'+ ArtistURL +'"><h2>' + val.artists.Artist + '</h2></a>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#update1').html(output);
});
```